# URL Handler not working in Goole app engine and flask Application

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, flask, flask-restful

I'm here to ask a silly question, unfortunately I can't figure out with it.

I have a Google app Engine project developed with Flask web framework.

The structure of my project is like that (in uppercase are the directories, while in lowercase the files):

```
> -PROJECT DIR
>     -APP
>         -API
>         -HANDLERS
>             home.py
>         -TEMPLATES
>             home.html
          - flask_app.py
>     app.yaml
>     appengine.config.pu
```

In home.py I am just rendering /TEMPLATES/home.html

```
from flask import render_template
from app.flask_app import app

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

This is the structure of `app.yaml` files:

```
 runtime: python27
 api_version: 1
 threadsafe: true

 handlers:
 - url: /.*
 script: app.flask_app.app
```

When i start to debugging and try to access localhost at `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` instead of rendering the templates it appears to me the following error `Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.`

Is that something wrong with app.yaml file? I think it is all correct, even the url.

EDIT
`flask_app.py`

```
import appengine_config
import logging

from app import app_secret_key
from flask import Flask
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect



app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
CSRF_PROTECT = CSRFProtect(app)


if appengine_config.GAE_DEV:
    logging.warning('Using a dummy secret key')
    app.secret_key = 'my_dummy_secret_key'
    app.debug = True
else:
    app.secret_key = app_secret_key.secret_key
```

Comment: Do you have `import HANDLERS.home` into your `flask_app.py` ? Have you tried locally before try on AppEngine ?

Comment: I am still trying locally but it doesn't work

Comment: Please update your question and add `flask_app.py` content, did you see your import at the top of home.py was wrong ? You are missing a space, so if no error is raised the reason is you don't import this file from `flask_app.py`

Comment: I have copied badly the import when I posted the question, but in my code is correct

Comment: Ok try to add `import HANDLERS.home` at the end of `flask_app.py`, this is very important. Or if this is not working, add your view/route inside `flask_app.py` instead of `home.py` just for your test

Comment: It Worked! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `import HANDLERS.home` at the end of `flask_app.py`

This is required on your application, Flask need to know which files register views or route.